# 2018 SF Novel - Spaceship mission, time travel

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel, spaceship

I recall reading about a new science fiction book published recently (2018).
I seem to remember that it maybe involved a spaceship mission, and that there was a time travel element.

I believe I read about it on io9 first but I can't locate it.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize there were specific rules on asking questions.

Comment: The goal is for you to help us help you. That means putting enough information in your question to distinguish it uniquely.

Comment: Is it better worded now?

Comment: If you've found it, you need to post a self-answer explaining what the answer was (and hopefully a little about how it matches your question). I've voted to reopen (since we've got an answer) but the question is still too terse.

Comment: I edited my original question, although I couldn't actually recall much information at the time, but the edits seem to have disappeared. Also am I supposed to see a Reply button to reply to my own question? A little hand holding would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've reverted the edits since we don't answer in the question box :-) Once the question is reopened you'll see an answer box appear below. Normally we wouldn't reopen a question as brief as this one but it seems a bit churlish to leave it closed when a user (in this case the original poster, e.g. you) knows the correct answer.

Comment: And now it's open again, you can self-answer. Then, when the timer runs out you can also self-accept. That way any users who come across this via search (or google) will know that it was the correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

I knew I had read about this novel on io9 so I went back and looked through their posts on reading lists.
I eventually found the novel.

It is *[The Gone World](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33413556-the-gone-world)* by Tom Sweterlitsch, published in 2018.

It's about an investigator tasked with investigating a murder.
Someone involved was part of a time travel program and their spaceship was lost on a mission.

> ***Inception meets True Detective in this science-fiction thriller of spellbinding tension and staggering scope. The Gone World follows a special agent into a savage murder case with grave implications for the fate of mankind.***
>
> Shannon Moss is part of a clandestine division within the Naval Criminal Investigative Service. In Western Pennsylvania, 1997, she is assigned to solve the murder of a Navy SEAL's family--and to locate his teenage daughter, who has disappeared. Though she can't share the information with conventional law enforcement, Moss discovers that the missing SEAL was an astronaut aboard the spaceship U.S.S. Libra--a ship assumed lost to the darkest currents of Deep Time. Moss knows first-hand the mental trauma of time-travel and believes the SEAL's experience with the future has triggered this violence.
>
> Determined to find the missing girl and driven by a troubling connection from her own past, Moss travels ahead in time to explore possible versions of the future, seeking evidence or insight that will crack the present-day case. To her horror, the future reveals that it's not only the fate of a family that hinges on her work, for what she witnesses rising over time's horizon and hurtling toward the present is the Terminus: the terrifying and cataclysmic end of humanity itself.
>
> Luminous and unsettling, The Gone World bristles with world-shattering ideas yet remains at its heart an intensely human story.

Comment: Ah. You can accept a self-answer to your own question within 48 hours of asking. For the sake of our own edification, can you share how you determined that this was your story?

Comment: Just brute force. It caught my eye back back in January, piqued my interest, then I forgot about it until for whatever reason I thought about it again and went looking for it. But I'm always on the lookout for a good time travel story as well.

Comment: ^_^ Ah, well, don't forget to accept it!

Comment: I'd never heard of this author or book until I saw this question thread.                Bought and downloaded now, I'm maybe a quarter way through reading it and am totally gripped by the book.                                                   Once again Stack Exchange has cost me money!

Comment: I sheepishly ask...is there an 'accept' button somewhere? I never noticed...sorry...